# get location based on image

Tags: java, image-processing, google-image-search

I am trying to get the location (preferably city name) based on any image uploaded.
 I can see similar functionality used in Google image search where we drag drop an image and it gives a lot of information including location.
 Is there any API (or any other way) through which I can get similar sort of information? I have checked [tineye](https://api.tineye.com/) but it requires commercial license so can't use that

Comment: are you quite sure that the google engine is using image processing to guess the location, or do you think it might be looking at the embedded metadata to see if there's a GPS tag?  Most mobiles add this now, so any pictures taken by phone are likely to have embedded GPS data, and will be trivial to get without image processing.  Try it with a "scrubbed" photo and see if you still get location.

Comment: I am not sure how Google do this. I have read articles about using meta tags but what about images which don't have that

Comment: I'm suggesting that for images that don't have meta tags, you aren't getting location data.  It would take a ton of processing power to search for similar photos and come to a consensus about where the photo was probably taken.  I doubt you'll get that for free just yet.

Comment: For instance, without location information, how would you know that a photo of the statue of liberty was the one in New York, or the one in Las Vegas?  Even the [US Post Office](http://www.reuters.com/article/2011/04/15/us-stamp-mixup-idUSTRE73E6BO20110415) has a difficult time figuring that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for this.
 Basically its using multiple google apis to get one result

1. Google Image Search API
   call the JSON api https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=http://www.aparisguide.com/eiffeltower/eiffel-tower1.jpg
   This will result json with information/content about image. We can use this content in step 2
2. Google Search api
    with the content or title obtained from previous search, try accessing google search api http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&q=Eiffel%20Tower
   this will return the lat and lng for search results as JSON
3. Google geocode api
    with the available lat and lng from previous search we can call the geocode api as below 
   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=48.858228,2.294388&sensor=true
   this will again return JSON with the list of possible address. With little processing of data it can give me the City.

Note: The results are not very consistent but it can solve the purpose to some extent